# Proper error handling with 2.0 style and WCF proxies

Tags: .net, client, asmx

Microsoft has provided surprisingly small amounts of information regarding this issue or I do not know enough about the problem to locate the documentation.

When consuming web services using the traditional VS2005 and .NET 2.0 web service proxies, aside from FaultExceptions, what sort of communication exceptions can be thrown and through which assemblies/namespaces.

I am having difficulty locating the equivilent to WCF's ServiceActivationException and CommunicationException from System.ServiceModel - are these the same exceptions?

Comment: I implemented the service calls using WCF style instead of 2.0 style and handled the exceptions how I normally do. Than you for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all WCF related exceptions descend from [CommunicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception.aspx) so if you consult the list of descendant classes in the MSDN documentation, you should be covered.

Exceptions are the generic `TimeOutException` (from the `System.Net` namespace) and the [QuotaExceeded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.quotaexceededexception.aspx) exception from the `System.ServiceModel` namespace which surprisingly does not descend from `CommunicationException` - why that is the case, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

An ASMX proxy can throw `SoapException`, or anything that can be thrown by `HttpWebRequest`.

However, you have to ask yourself: why do you care? What are you going to do differently between one exception type and another? Can you actually *handle* any of these exceptions, or will you simply log them and let them propagate (I hope you're not going to catch them and then ignore them).

Comment: I suppose your answer made me think a little, but I must admit I find it mostly offensive. Why would you make an assumption that I'm swallowing exceptions?

There was plenty of good information in your answer but the quality of my design work doesn't need to come into question.

Comment: Where did I _assume_ you're swallowing exceptions? I said "I **hope** you're not going to catch them and then ignore them".

Comment: It just came across as pedantic.

Comment: @Eugarps: of _course_ it's pedantic, I was trying to teach you why you don't need to, or want to, know all the possible exceptions.